# I managed to insert commas into a string using regular expression, but some help is needed

Tags: python, regex

```
import re
t="1234567890"
result = re.sub(r'(\d)(?=(\d{3})+$)',r'\1,',t)
print("insert commas every three digits",result)
```

this works fine:

```
insert commas every three digits: 1,234,567,890
```

while

```
t="1234567890"
result = re.sub(r'(\d)(?=(\d{3})+)$',r'\1,',t)
print("insert commas every three digits:",result)
```

doesn't.

```
insert commas every three digits: 1234567890
```

I truly do not understand why does $ doesnot work in the second code, some help is needed on this.

Comment: Why do this with regex? `format(int(t), ",")` will do it.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I'm still on my way learning regex, so I'm using some examples to learn it.

Answer (score 3):

The `$` anchor is part of the lookahead in the original regex: match a digit followed by groups of triple digits until end of line.

Your broken variant looks for a digit before end of line, with a lookahead requiring groups of triple digits after the matched digit but before end of line.

Comment: Thanks so much for this! It took me an hour to figure out why.